# Problem to apply replacement with regexp that include look ahead in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, regex

I have this kind of string `12s2-3a abc def` and I am trying to apply the regexp `^(?=.*\d)` to remove the first part and having as left `abc def`.

I have tried with:

`select substring ('12s2-3 abc def' from '^(?=.*\d)');`

and

`select regexp_replace ('12s2-3 abc def', '^(?=.*\d)', '');`

but none of those has worked. The only one that looks working is the match verification (`~`).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Look-ahead are zero width.  They don't match anything themselves.  So your replacement operations is just replacing the empty string with the empty string, under certain conditions.

Simply removing the look-ahead designation makes it give the answer you want for your one example:

```
select regexp_replace ('12s2-3 abc def', '^.*\d', '');
```